# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy redundant redirect to the login page

Tags: azure-ad-msal, angular15, msal-angular, msal

I'm using the MSAL Angular library with the Azure AD B2C Custom Policies for login, change password and other actions. There is a need to logout user whenever the browser is closed. In order to achieve that I have used the following configuration for the MSAL library:

```
cache: {
        cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.SessionStorage,
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    },
```

in combination with the following option:

```
loginRequest = {
    scopes: [],
    prompt: PromptState.SELECT_ACCOUNT
}
```

Now when user changes his password, or trying to impersonate, it redirects the user to the login page, even though the user is logged in. It is a redundant redirect to the login page. It shouldn't happen, there is no need to login the authenticated user.

I'm redirecting the user to the change password custom policy in the following way:

```
let changePasswordRequest: RedirectRequest | PopupRequest = {
            authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.customChangePassword.authority,
            scopes: [],
};
this.authService.loginRedirect(changePasswordRequest);

let impersonateUserRequest: RedirectRequest | PopupRequest = {
            authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.impersonateUser.authority,
            scopes: [],
};
this.authService.loginRedirect(impersonateUserRequest);
```

I have used the `this.authService.loginRedirect` function because I don't see any other way to redirect the user to the change password or another custom policy.

However, sometimes it redirects the user to the login page and sometimes - it's not. Any ideas how to get rid of the redundant redirect to the login page?